# Iterartion starts with 0

Tags: python

When i run the code below, the iteration starts from 0. I would like to change the row to start from row 1. How i do i change it? I tried typing rownum=1 before the iteration starts.

Code:

```
def triangle(rows):
    for rownum in range (rows):
        PrintingList = list()
        print ("Row no. %i" % rownum)
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = input("Please enter the %d number:" %iteration) 
            PrintingList.append(int(newValue))
            print()
def routes(rows,current_row=0,start=0):
           for i,num in enumerate(rows[current_row]): #gets the index and number of each number in the row
                if abs(i-start) > 1:   # Checks if it is within 1 number radius, if not it skips this one. Use if not (0 <= (i-start) < 2) to check in pyramid
                    continue
                if current_row == len(rows) - 1: # We are iterating through the last row so simply yield the number as it has no children
                    yield [num]
                else:
                    for child in routes(rows,current_row+1,i): #This is not the last row so get all children of this number and yield them
                         yield [num] + child 

numOfTries = input("Please enter the number of tries:")
Tries = int(numOfTries)
for count in range(Tries):
    numstr= input("Please enter the height:")
    rows = int(numstr)
    triangle(rows)
    routes(triangle)
    max(routes(triangle),key=sum)
```

Output :

```
Please enter the number of tries:2
Please enter the height:4
Row no. 0
Row no. 1
Please enter the 0 number:
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Python has a good documentation with a description of all functions: [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range), [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate). You should learn how to use it, it's invaluable.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Love the help provided.....

Comment: note that CamelCase names are usually class names in Python, not regular variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
for rownum in range (rows):
```

to:

```
for rownum in range (1, rows+1):
```

Answer (score 5):

`range()` can also take a starting value: `range(1, rows+1)`

For more information see the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: Note that this introduces an off-by-one bug.

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
for rownum in range (rows):
```

Into:

```
for rownum in range (1, rows+1):
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
def routes(rows,current_row=0,start=0):
```

to

```
def routes(rows,current_row=1,start=1):
```